# how to dynamically change the "href" depending on the browser url in html?

Tags: html

suppose currently by browser url is "www.xyz.com" and my href="/css/home.css".
Now my requirement is that, if the url changes to "www.xyza.com" or if it changes to say something like "www.xyzb.com " then my href should also change with the url provided to say href="/css/home_a.css" and href="/css/home_b.css" respectively.

Can someone please tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, could you provide an example? I dont see any sense by doing this

Answer (score 1):

you can get the current location with
document.write (document.location.href); 
and then change the href of the css with jquery,

$("a").attr("href", "/css/home_a.css")

Answer (score 0):

You can use server-side scripting to generate the right link. You didn't mention what you're using.

Or you could look at hostname and change the links with Javascript:

```
switch(document.location.host) {
    case "www.google.com": alert("Google"); break;
    default: alert("Other!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make a style switcher on the same domain, there are 2000 ways to do that, like for example easy to adapt to your specific question (unclear to me):

In your main page

```
<head>
<!-- bla bla -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" type="text/css" id="css" href="<?php echo switch_style();?>" />
<head>
```

In your style switch function

```
function build_css($style) {
    $css_file='style/'.$style.'/style.css'; // providing here your css path
    return $css_file;
}
function switch_style() {

    $style_dispo = array('default','style1','style2','style3','style4','style5');

    $current_style = ((isset($_SESSION['nav_style'])) AND ($_SESSION['nav_style'] != '')) ? $_SESSION['nav_style'] : 'default';

        // There you can adapt the style switch to your need, for example based on the $_SERVER(REQUEST_URI) in your case i/o a GET test case like here
    $new_style = (isset($_GET['style'])) ? $_GET['style'] : '';

    // style change
    if (($new_style != $current) AND ($new_style !=''))
    {
        if (in_array($new_style,$style_dispo))
        {
            $style= $new_style;
            $_SESSION['nav_style']=$style;
        }
        else
        {
            $style ='default';
            $_SESSION['nav_style']=$style;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $style = $current_style;
        $_SESSION['nav_style'] = $style;
    }
    return build_css($style);
}
```